# Excel interop conditional formatting with formula

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel-interop

I have two scenario, I'm developing with two pc, one with Visual Studio 2010, Office 2010, PIA 2010 and another PC with Visual Studio 2010, Office 2007, PIA 2007.
The same application have different behaviour, the first one works fine, the second one doesn't work.

I need to set a conditional formatting in a spreadsheet but with office 2007 it doesn't work because the formula in Excel is copy as string and not as formula. 
My code is the following for both office version:

```
Excel.Range cellToSet = worksheet.get_Range(startCell, endCell);
Excel.FormatConditions fcs = cellToSet.FormatConditions;
Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, "H4>=M4");
string str = fc.Formula1;
Excel.Interior interior = fc.Interior;
interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(backgroundColor);
```

The variable str is used to check the formula content after the Add calling, str returns the following: **"=\"H4>=M4\""** and the worksheet doesn't work properly. 
Opening the excel file, under the menu Conditional Formatting / Manager Rules / Show Formatting rules I see:
***Formula: ="H4>=M4"*** instead of ***Formula: =H4>=M4*** (without the characters ")

In the PC with office 2010 the str variable returns **"=H4>=M4"** (without the characters ") and the generated file works fine.

Why in office 2007 this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to used absolute Cell references as described in this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895562). So instead of:

```
 "H4>=M4" try "$H$4>=$M$4$".
```

Comment: The problem is not the reference to the cell but the formula content. I would like a mathematical chek in the excel sheet: =H4>=M4 instead with Office 2007 I have ="H4>=M4". This condition is always false because it checks if in the (numeric) cell there is the string "H4>=M4" instead of make the operation and return true if the value of H4 is bigger than the value in M4.

Comment: But did you try the proposed solution? Your code thinks your are trying to compare strings while with mine you explicitly tell that you are using references to the cells. Thats exactly what the linked articles says its the problem.

Comment: You're right, thank you very much, now it's work successfully. I don't belive that the $ could be necessary. Otherwise another error was in the code, the formula should be contain also the '=' character. So updating the formula to "=$H$4>=$M$4$" works fine. Thank you again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186695/why-isnt-trying-to-highlight-duplicate-cells-in-a-column-working-correctly Please help with this