# How do I get character count from cell

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-interop

**Goal:** I'm trying to add a feature to my Excel 2016 VSTO plugin. The feature will get 1 column from the active sheet, and iterate over it changing the background color based on string length.

**Problem:** I'm having trouble getting string length from the cells.  I can not figure out the proper syntax I currently have `var count = row.Item[1].Value2.Text.Length;`

**Code:** Here is what I have

```
    public void CharacterLengthCheck(int length = 24, int Column = 3)
    {
        Worksheet sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        var RowCount = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        Range column = sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[1, Column], sheet.Cells[RowCount, Column]];
        foreach (Range row in column)
        {
            var count = row.Item[1].Value2.Text.Length;
            if (count > length)
            {
                row.Item[1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            }
            else
            {
                row.Item[1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I'm having trouble getting string length from the cells`... What kind of trouble you are talking about...?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to build a conditional format or did you want the colors static when the text changes?

Comment: @Jeeped well can I build a conditional format with VSTO? Also this is for editing CSV files so I can't save any of that to the file.

Comment: How are you saving the static colors to a text file?

Comment: I'm not this is just a visual aid to help with editing the file in Excel, hence why I am using a plug-in to do this and not VBA, or simple formatting.

Comment: [Excel interop conditional formatting with formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083487/excel-interop-conditional-formatting-with-formula)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

`row.Item[1].Value2.Text.Length`

The length function is `Len(x)`, so try `Len(row.Item[1].Value2.Text)`

Comment: What name space is Len() in?

Comment: Woops I thought this was for Excel-VBA, not VSTO. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Jeeped for their advice on using conditional formatting. However the answer to my original question is.

Change

`var count = row.Item[1].Value2.Text.Length;`

to

```
string text = (row.Item[1].Value).ToString();
var count = text.length;
```

I believe this is because value is dynamic and needs to be explicitly cast to string